# Java double arrays references

Tags: java, arrays, variables, reference, double

First question here. I have put in comments and I am wondering is my terminology correct?

```
public class Wrapper {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int[][] intPrimative = new int[3][2]; 
        //create three pointers to arrays of size two
        System.out.println(intPrimative[2][1]);
        // prints default value 0;
        System.out.println(intPrimative[1]);
        // prints [I@74184b3b the reference to the second array

        Integer[][] intWrap = new Integer[3][2];
        System.out.println(intWrap[2][1]);
        System.out.println(intWrap[2]);
        // prints [Ljava.lang.Integer;@33d88c1f
        // the reference to an Intger array object

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a code review? [If so, we have a site for that.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can get rid of your `// TODO` comment. 

Comments generally go above the line its describing or on the same line at the end.

Your prints comment reference will most likely change every execution, so you don't want to put that.

Comment: What is your question? Is that about commenting?

Comment: I'm sorry it was not clear I was wondering if the comments in terms of references are acceptable or if they need correcting.  Thank you for pointing out comments go on top or at the side.  I know what the code does just not sure my comments are correct terminology.  I can not see the thing to thank people for help.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering is my terminology correct?

Well, inasmuch as the variable name `intPrimative` seems intended to incorporate the term "primitive", it is incorrectly spelled.

Also, the comment

```
//create three pointers to arrays of size two
```

reflects incorrect understanding and/or incorrect terminology, in that the term "pointer" is not used in Java context, except for in the (poorly chosen) name of the infamous `NullPointerException`.  The code is not well described as creating any pointers.  The bit you seem to be referring to creates an *array* of three `int` *arrays*, each one with length 2.

Additionally, where you comment

```
// prints [I@74184b3b the reference to the second array
```

it would be most correct to say that it prints the *string value* of the second array.  Part of that might be an address, but the whole is neither a reference nor a representation of one.  Your other comment about printing a reference is similarly wrong, or at best a poor choice of wording.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I meant to not say pointers.  I did in the at first where I said references but corrected it.                                                                   // prints [I@74184b3b the reference to the second array    now I'd thought that I'd be close enough with that statement.  So it prints the String value of the second array.   This is something I had not heard of before so I will look that up.  Thank you!